# TWordApplication and Word collision

Tags: delphi

I am using `TWordApplication` in Delphi. My app opens new instance of word and make something on  its document. Problem is when i first run my app and next open real word exe. Word exe didnt open new word instance but it link to my app instance. So when my app write to its document all text appears on exe word visible to user.

```
WordApp := TWordApplication.Create(nil);
WordApp.ConnectKind := ckNewInstance;
(WordApp.Documents.Add(EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam, varFalse ));
```

Then the user opens Word manually.

```
WordApp.Selection.Text := 'test test test';
```

And user see 'test test test' in manually opened Word.

If i first opens Word manually and starts my app all is ok.

Answer (score 4):

This is default behaviour of Word, it uses a running instance. What you have to do is store a reference to the document you want to modify. So don't use ActiveDocument, but use the Document you stored. Because there is no guarantee that ActiveDocument is the document you think it is.

```
//starting Word
var
  App: TWordApplication;
  Doc: WordDocument;
begin
  App := TWordApplication.Create(nil);
  Doc := App.Documents.AddOld(EmptyVar, EmptyVar); //open new document

<..somewhere else..>
  //modifying Word
  Doc.DoWhateverIWant;  // <--see? no ActiveDocument, so you are not 
                      //             modifying the users doc
```

Comment: +1 Regardless of how Word is openend, started or connected to, this is indeed the way to avoid "scratching" all over the currently visible document, whichever that may be...

Comment: Though I am not convinced Word re-uses a running *hidden* instance... (yet :-)

Comment: Convinced now. Don't remember it that way (D5/Word97) but Word(2007) now certainly re-uses even an hidden instance opened by an application...

Comment: @Marjan Venema: I don't remember it the other way around :)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you use

```
WordApp.ConnectKind := ckNewInstance;
```

to open your word application. Either do it in code (as above) or set the property at design time. This ensures that you are always running a new instance of Word and that it remains hidden unless you explicitely make it visible. <strike>Any user opening Word will then always get a different instance of Word and will not see what you have put on the document (unless you have saved it and they open the saved document).</strike>

From the doc:

> Set ConnectKind to indicate how the
>   ConnectKind component establishes a
>   connection. ConnectKind establishes
>   the connection when the application is
>   run (if AutoConnect is True true) or
>   when the application calls the Connect
>   (or ConnectTo) method.

The following table lists the possible values:

```
//Value                Meaning  
//ckRunningOrNew       Attach to a running server or create a new instance of the server.   
//ckNewInstance        Always create a new instance of the server.   
//ckRunningInstance    Only attach to a running instance of the server.   
//ckRemote             Bind to a remote instance of the server. When using this option,
//                     you must supply a value for RemoteMachineName.   
//ckAttachToInterface  Don't bind to the server. Instead, the application supplies an
//                     interface using the ConnectTo method, which is introduced in
//                     descendant classes. This option can't be used with the AutoConnect
//                     property.
```

**Update**

Actually, opening Word may have opened a different instance (that's how I remember it for D5/Word97), but at the moment Word does indeed re-use the instance opened by the application. So to avoid "scratching all over a word document manually opened by a user" you really do need to avoid using ActiveDocument as per The_Fox's answer.

Comment: I set it. But is not the point. Iam start my app. New instance is created. I start Word.exe and Word window appear. And Word.exe didnt start new instance. So my app write in Word window.

Comment: Then, as I said in my comment to your question: show your code. We are not clair voyant and cannot help you if you don't show us what exactly you are doing. And how is the user starting Word? Clicking a short cut or double-clicking a document?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't submit that comment... Question remains: please show us your code.

Comment: Setting ConnectKind to ckNewInstance is not going to help, because the Word instance is created, and then a user opens Word manually.

Comment: @The_Fox: Really? That would mean MS Office always open its instances with ckRunningOrNew? This I think is not the case, certainly not for Excel. The only way to get Excel to show two different views is to start two separate instances, which means ckNewInstance is used, but only if you use a short cut to the application and do not just double click on a document... Double clicking a document does indeed use ckRunningOrNew, which is why I asked how OP opened the document.

Comment: @The_Fox: I checked and you are absolutely right, see update to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210565  there are several command line switches that will cause Word to start a new instance.  The one I have used with Word2003 is /x